# Max distance of random walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-walk

Say a 1D random walk starts at the origin. At every time step, the random walk advances $+1$ with probability $\alpha$, stays at its current location with probability $\beta$, and returns to the origin with probability $1-\alpha-\beta$. Once the random walk returns to the origin, the walk is over, no future movement occurs.

My question is, what is the distribution of the maximum distance from the origin reached on the random walk? Is it perhaps an exponential or power-law distribution?

Thank you for any suggestions or feedback.

Comment: Get rid of the "stays the same location" probability, as this doesn't affect the outcome. You only care if it moves forwards to backwards. So you only need one variable $\ \alpha.$

Comment: Good insight! Without the "staying the same" branch, the problem is now trivial.

Comment: But to solve it without the insight is also straight forward.  Get the joint distribution of $m$ up moves, $k$ same moves and one ending home move.  Then summing over $k$ (with the aid of a well-known combinatorial identity) gets you the same result.